# Why is there just 1 job id in dataproc when there are multiple actions in the pyspark script?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc, dataproc

The definition of spark job is:

> Job- A parallel computation consisting of multiple tasks that gets spawned in response to a Spark action (e.g. save, collect); you'll see this term used in the driver's logs.

So, why is it that each `spark-submit` creates just one job id in dataproc console that I can see?

Example: The following application should have 2 spark jobs

```
sc.parallelize(range(1000),10).collect()
sc.parallelize(range(1000),10).collect()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between Dataproc job and Spark job. When you submit the script through Dataproc API/CLI, it creates a Dataproc job, which in turn calls `spark-submit` to submit the script to Spark. But inside Spark, the code above does create 2 Spark jobs. You can see it in the Spark UI:

[image: Spark UI]